# Why am I getting "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address" here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

The relevant code is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetLinkByName ( string pname )
    {
        PartnerIdAndEmail PInfo = this._Db.GetPartnerByName(pname);
        if ( PInfo != null )
        {
            try
            {
                var m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                {
                    Subject = "Your Survey Link",
                    Body = String.Format("<p>Your survey link is <a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a></p>", 
                                          String.Format("{0}Answers/FillOut?pid={1}",this.GetBaseUrl(),PInfo.Id)),
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                };
                m.From = new MailAddress("admin@mycompany.com", "Administrator"); // placeholder of the address I'm sending the email from
                m.To.Add(PInfo.Email);
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "something@somethingelse.net", // this is a placeholder of the value of "SMTP Server" in my IIS
                    Port = 25, // this is the value of "Port" in my IIS
                    Credentials = null,
                    EnableSsl = false
                };
                smtp.Send(m); 
            } catch (Exception e) { return Json(new { succeeded = false, msg = e.Message }); }
            // If here, we can assume the message was successfully sent
            return Json(new { succeeded = true, msg = "Thanks! You should receive an email with your survey link soon." });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new {
                succeeded = false,
                msg = String.Format("Oops! There was a problem in finding the info for partner {0}", pname)
            });
        }

    }
```

and I can't figure out the exact line since it's a run-time error. I've verified that `PInfo.Email` when I run the program is a valid email address. So I don't know what could be the problem here. Any ideas? Or any suggestions for how I can debug this?

Comment: Try debugging `PInfo.Email` right before the `To` is called, maybe there is something that changing this address.

Comment: It can also be your [return address is bogus](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/499/how-to-handle-the-error-the-specified-string-is-not-in-the-form-required-for-an-e-mail-address) so check that too.

Comment: `Host = "something@somethingelse.net"` doesn't make sense either. You need a hostname, not an email address.